# Compare two excel sheets in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two excel sheets- Sheet1 & sheet2. Column A value from sheet1 is compared to Column A all values from sheet2. If matches then column C value from matched row from sheet2 is copied to column C in sheet1.

Sheet1

```
    Serial    Value
    123        
    345 
    567
    890
    120
    123
    345
    123
    890
```

Sheet2

```
    Serial   Value
    123      Name
    890      Class
    123      Name
    345      Division
    567      School
    123      Name
```

After code run, Sheet1 should be:

```
    Serial     Value
    123        Name
    345        Division
    567        School
    890        Class
    120
    123        Name
    345        Division
    123        Name
    890        Class
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you try to solve the problem? Why would you need pandas to solve this?

Comment: Yes I tried it with Python code, but not able to do it. Need help to solve it using python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pandas' `map` method:

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
Sheet1 = pd.DataFrame({'Serial': [123, 345, 567, 890, 120, 123, 345, 123, 890]})
Sheet2 = pd.DataFrame({'Serial': [123, 890, 123, 345, 567, 123], 
                       'Value': ['Name', 'Class', 'Name', 'Division', 'School', 'Name']})

# transform Sheet2 into a dictionary that we can use as the mapping function
key = pd.Series(list(Sheet2['Value']), index=Sheet2['Serial']).to_dict()

# apply this mapping function to Sheet1
Sheet1['Value'] = Sheet1['Serial'].map(key)

# show results
display(Sheet1)
```

Output:

```
 Serial     Value
0   123     Name
1   345     Division
2   567     School
3   890     Class
4   120     NaN
5   123     Name
6   345     Division
7   123     Name
8   890     Class
```